# Is there any use for a python property getter?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is any use for explicitly using the getter decorator for class properties:

```
class A:
    @property
    def p(self):
       return self._p

    @p.setter
    def p(self, val):
       assert p < 1000
       self._p = val

    @p.getter
    def p(self):
       return self._p
```

why would I ever explicitly use the getter here?  Doesn't it render the code within p(self) unreachable?  Basically, is there any practical reason to use it?

Comment: No reason in your particular case, but think of a more sophisticated approach.
I.e. lazy initialization (say, value returned generated on first call). For example, lazy connection to database

Comment: I can imagine that use case, but it seems I could just put that code under the @property definition of p rather than explicitly defining a p.getter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's useful when you inherit a property from a parent class and want to override the getter:

```
class Parent:
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return 'Parent'

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        print('prop is now', value)


class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.prop.getter
    def prop(self):
        return 'Child'
```

This creates a copy of `Foo.prop` with a different getter function but the same setter (and deleter).